# INSERT INTO MYSQL - Can´t insert data

Tags: mysql, forms, post, insert-into

After a couple of week´s trying to insert data in variables from `form` in MYSQL database, i´m asking here. I found a lot of example codes of `INSERT INTO` and also my provider checked my skript. He said I have a problem in my `$sql=`.
I tryed a lot of, but i can´t see any data in phpMyAdmin after click submit, but i receive the mail, that works fine.
Maybe anybody can see an issue in my script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["sendcopy"])){
mail($mailToCC, $subject, $textCC, $from);
}

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$host_name = "database.myprovider";
$database = "db_name";
$user_name = "user_name";
$password = "*****************";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "KEINE VERBINDUNG MÖGLICH! " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
else
{
echo "ERFOLGREICHE VERBINDUNG ZUR DATENBANK!";}

$sql= 'INSERT INTO "offen"("id", "vorname", "nachname", "email", "telefon", "geburtsjahr", "postleitzahl", "datum", "stunde", "minute", "personen", "bereich", "nachricht")
    VALUES ($id, $vorname, $nachname, $email, $tel, $geburtsjahr, $plz, $datum, $stunde, $minute, $personen, $bereich, $nachricht)';

mysql_close($connect);
}

include ("reservtrue.php");
exit;
?>
```

The `"submit"` comes from a `<form>` below.

```
<form method="post" action="mailer.php" onsubmit="return chkFormular()" name="Formular" id="formTemplate">
<table id="reservtable">
.
.
.
.
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Reservieren" id="submit">
    </td>
        </tr>
            </table>
               </form>
```

I hope it´s no problem to use german words as variables, here in stackoverflow.

Thank´s for help.

---

**EDIT**

Thank you for you´r suggestions. I still can´t insert data from `form` to MYSQL. I changed my Code a bit. And if I paste the code into phpMyAdmin - SQL, it work´s! But not if I load my script to server and test my form in web.
This is my new Code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

$vorname = $_POST["Vorname"];
$nachname = $_POST["Nachname"];
$email = $_POST["Mailadresse"];
$tel = $_POST["Telefonnummer"];
$geburtsjahr = $_POST["Geburtsjahr"];
$plz = $_POST["PLZ"];
$datum = $_POST["Datum"];
$stunde = $_POST["Stunde"];
$minute = $_POST["Minute"];
$personen = $_POST["Personen"];
$bereich = $_POST["Bereich"];
$nachricht = $_POST["Nachricht"];

$host_name = "database.myprovider";
$database = "db_name";
$user_name = "user_name";
$password = "*****************";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "KEINE VERBINDUNG MÖGLICH! " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
        else
        {
        echo "ERFOLGREICHE VERBINDUNG ZUR DATENBANK!";}

$insert = ("INSERT INTO offen(vorname, nachname, email, telefon, geburtsjahr, postleitzahl, datum, stunde, minute, personen, bereich, nachricht)
VALUES ('".$id."', '".$vorname."', '".$nachname."', '".$email."', '".$tel."', '".$geburtsjahr."', '".$plz."', '".$datum."', '".$stunde."', '".$minute."', '".$personen."', '".$bereich2."', '".$nachricht."')");

mysqli_query($insert, $sql);
}

include ("reservtrue.php");
exit;
?>
```

**Problem solved**

Problem is solved with following code:

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO `offene`
(
`id`, `vorname`, `nachname`, `email`, `telefon`, `geburtsjahr`, `postleitzahl`, `datum`, `stunde`, `minute`, `personen`, `bereich`, `nachricht`
)
VALUES
(
NULL, '$vorname', '$nachname', '$email', '$tel', '$geburtsjahr', '$plz', '$datum', '$stunde', '$minute', '$personen', '$bereich', '$nachricht');";

mysqli_query($connect, $insert);
```

Thank you guy´s for information, inspriation and tips! I learnd a lot in the last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `mysql_query($sql);` ? Add this after your `$sql`. Your `$sql` query require `mysql_query` to run it. If you added that and it still doesn't work, I suggest your go to phpmyadmin's sql tab. Paste your query in with some random VALUES. That's how I check if my query is working or not.

Comment: Your sql query is not doing anything, it's just sitting there.

Comment: phpMyAdmin gives error like: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '$sql = "INSERT INTO offen (id, vorname...

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "ERFOLGREICHE VERBINDUNG ZUR DATENBANK!";}

$sql= 'INSERT INTO offen (id, vorname, nachname, email, telefon, geburtsjahr, postleitzahl, datum, stunde, minute, personen, bereich, nachricht)
    VALUES ('$id', '$vorname', '$nachname', '$email', '$tel', '$geburtsjahr', '$plz', '$datum', '$stunde', '$minute', '$personen', '$bereich', '$nachricht')';

mysqli_query($connect,$sql); //this line was missing from your code.
mysqli_close($connect); //updated to make it MySQLi
```

The `mysqli_query($connect,$sql)` actually does the work of applying the SQL you define in the `$sql` query.

**NOTE**

- You have both *MySQLi* and *MySQL* functions in your script, you must stick with just one function, ALL your SQL functions must be MySQL ***i*** .
- I would recommend that you change your SQL query to use single quotes and backticks. The table name `offen` and the column names do not need to be in quotes. The variables you insert do need to be in quotes, as I have illustrated.
- You do not (usually) need to have `mysqli_close` because the SQL connection automatically closes once the PHP reaches the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

The variable names don't need quotes but the parametes do.  Also you are missing the code to execute the SQL statement.

```
echo "ERFOLGREICHE VERBINDUNG ZUR DATENBANK!";}

$sql= "INSERT INTO offen(id, vorname, nachname, email, telefon, geburtsjahr, postleitzahl, datum, stunde, minute, personen, bereich, nachricht)
VALUES ($id, '$vorname', '$nachname', '$email', '$tel', '$geburtsjahr', '$plz', '$datum', '$stunde', '$minute', '$personen', '$bereich', '$nachricht')";

if ($connect->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $connect->error;
}

mysql_close($connect);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have some understandable confusion about quoting of the variables in `$insert`.   You likely have a problem with how you are handling your datatypes.

Here are a few things to look out for

1. You have too many quotes around your variables.  Wrap the query in `""` but save the `''` for individual variables (where necessary, seen below).  For instance, just wrap the variable **once** like so: `.'$vorname'.' if the variable you are inputting is a string.   If it is an integer (INT variable type), leave the quotes off, e.g.`$number`.   In other words, input strings as strings, and INT as int.
2. If the variable you wish to input is set as auto-increment in your database (i.e. it is the primary key), you probably don't want to be inputting it at all.    For example, in your case `$id` appears to be one. If this is true, you have the syntax backward.  Just input it as `NULL` or leave it off the insert, like so:   `insert into tablename (id, vorname) values (NULL, '$vorname')`
3. You need to also sanitize your ALL of your variables if you to prevent SQL Injection (very possible with your code).  You can do this with `mysqli_real_escape_string()`

**OR** instead of going through all of that,  you could use **prepared statements**, which would both handle that information in a cleaner way, but also would protect your code against SQL injection.

Here's how to do this using `mysqli`:

Connect as an object:

```
$connect = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $password, $database);
```

And then feed your query into the object and bind the parameters.  In this section, "s" is a string, "i" is an integer.

```
$insert = $connect->prepare("INSERT INTO offen(id, vorname, nachname, email)
VALUES (NULL, ?,?,?");
$insert->bind_param("sss", $vorname, $nachname, $email);
$insert->execute();
$insert->close();
```

If you name your variables correctly, this should work.

Comment: (note, I made a syntax error in the prepared statement, so if you are looking at it make sure to reload)